Adding shipping_email to the woocommerce shipping object
I am trying to add a custom field for the recipient's email address (shipping_email) to the WooCommerce checkout under the shipping details. The goal is for this field to be stored as part of the shipping information and sent as part of the standard WooCommerce shipping object to be picked up by a delivery partner.
I need a way to include shipping_email into the native shipping address structure so it is treated like other shipping fields. For instance, shipping_phone was not included as default shipping field, but when added it appears alongside other shipping details and is picked up by the delivery partner. This doesn't happen with the shipping_email.
While I can add the field both manually and via plugins, save the field as metadata, have it appear in order confirmations etc. it does not integrate directly into the shipping address object. Every attempt to force it into the native shipping object results in failure to complete the order.
Other attempts where orders go through, the shipping_email does not appear in the order confirmation as part of the shipping details, but appears "outside" as an additional field. As a result, our third-party delivery partner do not pick it up as the recipients email.
I've tried many alternatives in my functions.php…
In this attempt, I try to manually add the shipping field to the shipping form and force it into the shipping object, resulting in WooCommerce failing to process the order:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'legg_til_mottaker_epost' );
    function legg_til_mottaker_epost( $felt ) {
    $felt['shipping']['shipping_email'] = array(
        'type'        => 'email',
        'label'       => __( 'E-postadresse', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'mottaker@eksempel.no', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'    => true,
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'priority'    => 25,
    );
    return $felt;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'lagre_shipping_epost', 10, 2 );
    function lagre_shipping_epost( $ordre, $data ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) ) {
        $ordre->set_shipping_email( sanitize_email( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) );
    }
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_formatted_shipping_address', 'vis_shipping_epost_i_adresse', 10, 2 );
    function vis_shipping_epost_i_adresse( $adresse, $ordre ) {
    if ( ! empty( $ordre->get_shipping_email() ) ) {
        $adresse .= '<br>' . __( 'E-post:', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ' . esc_html( $ordre->get_shipping_email() );
    }
    return $adresse;
}

I've also tried adding it as meta, which ensures orders are processed and shipping_email appears in emails and order confirmations, but not directly within the delivery object, the same way as shipping_phone does:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'legg_til_mottaker_epost_felt' );
    function legg_til_mottaker_epost_felt( $felt ) {
    $felt['shipping']['shipping_email'] = array(
        'type'        => 'email',
        'label'       => __( 'E-postadresse', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'mottaker@eksempel.no', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'    => true,
        'class'       => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'priority'    => 25,
    );
    return $felt;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'lagre_shipping_epost_meta' );
    function lagre_shipping_epost_meta( $ordre_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $ordre_id, '_shipping_email', sanitize_email( $_POST['shipping_email'] ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'vis_shipping_epost_i_admin' );
    function vis_shipping_epost_i_admin( $ordre ) {
    $shipping_email = get_post_meta( $ordre->get_id(), '_shipping_email', true );
    if ( ! empty( $shipping_email ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Mottakers e-postadresse:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . esc_html( $shipping_email ) . '</p>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'vis_shipping_epost_i_epost', 20, 3 );
    function vis_shipping_epost_i_epost( $ordre, $sendt_til_admin, $plain_text ) {
    $shipping_email = get_post_meta( $ordre->get_id(), '_shipping_email', true );
    if ( ! empty( $shipping_email ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Mottakers e-postadresse:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong> ' . esc_html( $shipping_email ) . '</p>';
    }
}

Screenshot order confirmation:

